# Why there is a dely between 2 memory block of the while accesing?

Tags: memory, verilog

I am building a Modulo reduction module for the Elleptic Curve Crypto System. I want to access the Ram such that 2 address is read in 2 clock pulses. but my code is giving a lag such that it is becoming 3.

```
    module memtest3(
    input memread,
    input memwrite,
    input [3:0] addr0,
    input [3:0] addr1,
    input clk,load0,load1,
    input [31:0] write_data1,
    input [31:0] write_data0,
    output reg [31:0] read_data1,
    output reg [31:0] read_data0);
    reg [3:0] addr [1:0];
    reg [31:0] memo [10:0]; 
    //----------------<Memory module>-----------------//
    integer i,j;
    initial begin
       for(i=0;i<11;i=i+1)begin
        memo[i]<=i;
       end
    end
    always @(posedge clk)begin
        if(memwrite==1'b1)begin
            memo[addr[0]]<=write_data0;
            memo[addr[1]]<=write_data1;
        end
        else if(memread==1'b1) begin
            read_data0<=memo[addr[0]];
            read_data1<=memo[addr[1]];
        end     
    end
  //----------------<Memory Addressing>----------------//
    always @(posedge clk)begin
    /*if(memread==1'b1)begin
            if(i<<5)begin
                addr[0]<=i;
                addr[1]<=i+1;
           i<=i+2;
             end
        end*/
       if(memread==1'b1)begin
            if(i<<4)begin
               if(load0==1'b1)begin
                    addr[0]<=i;
                    addr[1]<=i+1;
               end
               else if(load1==1'b1)begin
                    addr[0]<=i;
                    addr[1]<=i+1;
               end
               i<=i+2;
             end
         end
      end

      endmodule
```

if i change i to i+7 then it is taking a more time to read the data of addr[0]. Can you help me out. I'm out of clue.

Comment: In your scheme the address you prepared at a clock edge will only be applied to the memory operations at the **following** clock edge. Is this what you want?

Comment: No i donot want that. actually when ever i try to access 2 memory symultaneously i see a big delay between both the output.

Comment: Do i need to put both in same always block?

Comment: In this case the address should be assigned as a pure combinational logic (no flop). You would probably need to move calculation of `i` to the end of the flop logic of the `memo` flop.

Comment: Please elaborate i didn't understand what you said. sorry..

Comment: i tried to explain it in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have 2 latches like this:

```
always @(posedge clk)
    a <= b;

always @(posedge clk)
    b <= c;
```

the result of `a` after the posedge will be the old value of `b`.
So, if `b` was 1 and `c` was 2, at the posedge

```
a --> 1 (old b)
b --> 2 (old c)
```

if you need to guarantee that `a` gets new value of `b`, you have a couple of choices:

1) calculate `b` using a combinational process:

```
  always @(*)
     b = c;
```

2) assign b at negedge of clk

```
  always @(negedge clk)
      b <= c;
```

3) you can make sure that your `b` has the value which you need at the particular clockedge by evaluating it in the current phase, something like the following.

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
     a <= b;
     next_b <= c;
end

always @*
   b = next_b;
```

there are other ways which could but limitation on the variables. For example, if `b` is just a temporary variable used inside the flop logic, you can use blocking assignments to evaluate it. But do not use it anywhere else:

```
 always @(posedge clk) begin
    b = c;  // b only used inside this block and uses BA
    a <= b;
 end
```

You have to think  which method better suits you better. Probably incrementing `i` at the negedge can work. You have to understand how the 'memread' is evaluated too.